# Is it possible to define Cucumber test step definition in Java interface?

Tags: java, cucumber, automated-tests

I want to define Cucumber test steps definition in Java interface.

```
public interface ITestSteps {
    @Before
    public void setUpLocal() throws Throwable;

    @When("^Landing screen is visible$")
    public void Landing_Screen_is_visible() throws Throwable;
}
```

2 other classes will implement this interface:

```
public class AppleTestSteps implements ITestSteps { ... } 
public class AndroidTestSteps implements ITestSteps { ... }
```

I have TestFactory class that get property with enviroment name (Android or Apple) and initialize object:

```
ITestSteps steps = TestFactory(platformName);
```

**Problem:** Cucumber takes needed step by name, without reference to the object. Takes `Landing_Screen_is_visible()` not a `steps.Landing_Screen_is_visible()`

Is it possible to implement interface before Cucumber try to find need step by name? Make static?

Or may be there is another way of implementation Cucumber steps? (Same steps but different implementation)

Answer (score 0):

what your looking for is the driver pattern where you have the same steps defs but use a different application driver when used in different test environments example

```
abstract class MyApplicationDriver {

     abstract void login();
```

then implementation for Android

```
class AndriodApplicationDriver extends MyApplicationDriver {

     void login(){};
```

and then another

```
class AppleTestDriver extends MyApplicationDriver {

    void login(){};
```

use the MyApplicationDriver as the interface in the tests and then use the implementation in the context , you have to look at the World object on how to do this